# Execute parent javascript on link click event in embedded pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an embedded pdf with html5-object tag.

```
<object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

In this pdf are several links. Now I want to perform a javascript method on the page that embedds the pdf.

This could either be made with triggering the method via the link in the pdf or a specific event from the parent page (jquery event listener?).

Has anyone an idea or codesnippet how to make something like that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you haven't seen it, this can give you a pointer. Note that it's an API reference specific to Adobe Reader; other readers may not support this, and my instinct is that it isn't possible to do what you're asking. But I have no direct experience with this, so good luck! http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf

Comment: Thanks... unfortunatelly the API doesnt offer something useful... :(